# Python - re.sub for non-ascii character

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, unicode

I am trying to use regex to match a specific pattern and delete the entire pattern. 
example: "Leave ≺random text here≻Other text"

I need it to end up like this "Leave Other test". Now i converted my script to use unicode but it refuses to find the string in the list.

I tried to call for it based of the literal value and also it's hex alternative (found using a hex editor to find the exact hex code of the symbol, utf-8 symbol).

Keep in mind the '≻' is not the same as '>'.

Tried:

```
eleInfo = "Leave ≺random text here≻Other text"

eleInfo = re.sub("≺.*?≻","",eleInfo)
```

Tried:

```
eleInfo = "Leave ≺random text here≻Other text"

eleInfo = re.sub("\x89\xBA.*?\x89\xBB","",eleInfo)
```

Tried:

```
eleInfo = "Leave ≺random text here≻Other text"

eleInfo = re.sub("\\x89\\xBA.*?\\x89\\xBB","",eleInfo)
```

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing **\xe2**. The following works:

```
re.sub("\\xe2\\x89\\xba.*\\xe2\\x89\\xbb","",eleInfo)
```

*Additionally*, you can convert the string to unicode

```
eleInfo = unicode("Leave ≺random text here≻Other text")
```

and

```
re.sub(u"[\u227a].*[\u227b]","",eleInfo) works too.
```

Comment: What's weird is I already had that and it didn't work. Maybe linux is spewing out the symbol improperly. Either way you are right, this does work. It must be linux breaking the symbol when calling it from the xml file and making the string. Thanks!